# About the integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} (\sin x-1)/\ln(\sin x) \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, gamma-function, digamma-function, leibniz-integral-rule

Using the Feynman Technique,

Let $$I(a) := \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{(\sin x)^a - 1}{\ln(\sin x)} \mathrm{d}x$$

$$I’(a)= \int_0^{\pi/2} (\sin x)^a \mathrm{d}x
     = \frac{\sqrt{π}}{2}  \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)}{ \Gamma\left(\frac{a+2}{2}\right)}$$

$$I(a)= \frac{\sqrt{π}}{4}  \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)\left(\psi\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{a+2}{2}\right)\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+2}{2}\right)} +C$$

The constant I’ve got is $\frac{π \ln 2}{2}$.

Therefore,

$$\begin{split} \int_0^{π/2} (\sin x-1)/\ln(\sin x) \mathrm{d}x
&= I(1)\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{π}}{4} \frac{\Gamma(1)(\psi(1)-\psi(3/2))}{\Gamma(3/2)} + \frac{\pi \ln 2}{2}\\
&= \frac{1}{2} (2\ln 2 -2) + \frac{\pi \ln 2}{2}\\
&= \ln 2 - 1 + \frac{\pi \ln 2}{2}\\
&\approx 0.782 \end{split}$$

But WolframAlpha gave me the result about $1.23$.

What mistakes did I just make?Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You should try to write math using MathJax, it's pretty much LaTeX if you're familiar with that. You can right-click on any MathJax expression to see the code used to write it, which lets you learn some symbols or tricks here and there from the other users. Did you mean to make the integral in the last caluclation from $0$ to $1$ or should the upper bound be $\pi/2$ like the rest? By the way, feel free to edit in case I mis-MathJax'd what you wanted to write.

Comment: Thanks.I have fixed the upper bound.It should be π/2

Comment: If you want your reasoning to be checked, write in detail how you integrate $I'(a)$ and find $C$.

Comment: Your $I(a)=...+C$ is actually the derivative not definite integral :).

Comment: It might be helpful that the original integral is equivalent to $$\int_0^1 \sqrt\frac{1 - u}{1 + u} \frac{du}{\log u}.$$

Answer (score 3):

The quantity $$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}  \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)\left(\psi\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{a+2}{2}\right)\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+2}{2}\right)}$$ is $I''(a)$, not $I(a)$ as you wrote. I don't know how to express $$I(1) - I(0) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+2}{2}\right)} \,da$$ in simpler terms, nor does Mathematica or Maple.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compute $$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+2}{2}\right)} \,da$$ you can approximate the integrand by its $P_{n,n}$ Padé approximant built around $a=0$.

Then, for $n \leq 3$, partial fraction decomposition leads to (very nasty) explicit results. Converted to decimals, the numerical valus are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \int_0^1 P_{n,n}\, da \\
 1 & \color{red}{1.38}68540 \\
 2 & \color{red}{1.3833}219 \\
 3 & \color{red}{1.3833026} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$